# JSF and Jquery AJAX - How can I make them work together?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I'm just starting out in JSF, looks awesome, but I can't seem to figure out this last barrier.

I'm used to traditional Jquery AJAX function, which is perfect in my book. But I was hoping to find a way to get it to work in harmony with JSF.

Here is a scenario to explain my situation.

I have a messaging page on my website, where users can send each other messages. So in my xhtml page I have something that looks like this:

```
<h:form>
<h:inputTextarea id="newMessageContent" value="#{conversationBean.newMessage}"/>
<h:commandButton value="#{siteLang.messages_send}" action="#{conversationBean.sendMessage}">
     <f:ajax render=":conversationMessages" execute="newMessageContent"/>
</h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Works great. Users can post their message and it loads it in the conversation div above.  But now I need to add some features.
     - When user clicks, the button and textarea should get disabled to avoid interaction until the action is completed.  And a loader should appear
     - When the JSF finishes it's stuff, the textarea and button should get enabled and the loader should disappear...and the focus goes back to the textarea.

In Jquery I would simply do something like this:

```
$.ajax{
    beforeSend: function (){
         // Disable textarea and button, show loader
    },
    complete: function () {
         // Do the inverse of above
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add the `onevent="jsFunctionName"`  (no brackets) needed to your `<f:ajax`

and your `jsFunctionName` should look like

```
function openDeleteDevicesDialog(data) {
    console.log(data.status); //while ,data.status can be 1)"begin" 2)"complete" 3)"success"
    if (data.status === 'begin') {...}
    if (data.status === 'complete') {...}
    if (data.status === 'success') {...}
}
```

so you should enter this function 3 times

the onclick of the `h:commandButton` is executed before the `f:ajax` even begins...)

**Note that usually you will execute your code in the when `data.status === 'success'` , its when your page is done rendering and your DOM is in its final shape/state**

[also take a look at BalusC answer over here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7044332/617373)

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for? [How can I execute Javascript before a JSF <h:commandLink> action is performed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628/how-can-i-execute-javascript-before-a-jsf-hcommandlink-action-is-performed) (you will have to change the link to the button)

If you see this button being used everywhere on your web site, you can also create a custom tag.

Comment: Almost...except I need a function to be fired before the submit and another different one after the submit (which also depends on the feedback in case there is an error...)