# JSF execute javascript after f:ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

In my JSF 2 web application, I use the following code to display and switch the contents of a rich:dataTable according to the selectedStatus:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="statusSelection" value="#{backingBean.selectedStatus}" style="width:auto; float:left;">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="AVAILABLE" itemLabel="Available" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="INACTIVE" itemLabel="Inactive" />
  <f:ajax render="itemsDataTable" execute="#{backingBean.sortByTitel('ascending')}" />
  <f:ajax render="itemsDataTable" event="click" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

The dataTable contains a4j:commandLink s, which unintentionally need to be double clicked in some IE versions after changing table content - I found out, that executing the following Javascript code (on IE's debugging console, after table contents have changed) solves the issue:

```
document.getElementById(<dataTableClientId>).focus()
```

My question is: How can I achieve automatic execution of the javascript code after the table contents have changed?

Comment: Can you do a test? Take out **<f:ajax render="itemsDataTable" event="click" />**

Comment: I tried, result: If I take out this tag, everything is fine in firefox, but in the IE versions causing trouble, it gets even worse: Switching the table content won't work, the tables switch by clicking the wrong radio button,...

Comment: As you are using a h:selectOneRadio try to change the event to onchange instead of click. The click event happens before you choose the option in the select.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to execute JS code after the `<f:ajax>` is successfully completed, the following inline solution will do:

```xml
<f:ajax
    render="itemsDataTable" 
    onevent="function(data) { if (data.status === 'success') { 
        // Put your JS code here.
        document.getElementById('dataTableClientId').focus();
    }}" />
```

Or the following external function solution (note: do not put parentheses in `onevent`, only the function name):

```xml
<f:ajax
    render="itemsDataTable" 
    onevent="scriptFunctionName" />
```

```
function scriptFunctionName(data) {
    if (data.status === 'success') { 
        // Put your JS code here.
        document.getElementById('dataTableClientId').focus();
    }
}
```

Also take a look at this answer: [JSF and Jquery AJAX - How can I make them work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083561/617373)

Also, double check the need of the `event="click"` in your `f:ajax` , because the default event in `<h:selectOneRadio>` is `change` which I think you better use... See also [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/)