# JSF 2 Drop down with JavaScript and Ajax support

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsf-2

I have very specific requirement that uses JavaScript, JSF 2 and Ajax feature of JSF 2. I have a drop-down list with two values. Say A and B.

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="sampleList" value="#{beanName.tempValue}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select value..." itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="a" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="b" />
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{beanName.actionMethodToNavigate}" onevent="if (this.value=='0'){ return false;} else if (this.value=='a'){jumpToAhchor('#listItems');return false;}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

If the drop down value is "a" then user stays on the same page and anchors to other element down on the same screen using JavaScript. If the value is B then it calls bean method, which eventually navigates user to other screen.

I have tried to search many examples, and many suggest to put JavaScript in onevent attribute. But it does not work in my case and getting this console error in browser.

[image]

Comment: You need to more code, for example - your JS code etc. Provided code is too less to find the root cause ..

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. But I found a solution, and realized that i was doing it wrong. "onevent" accepts function name not JavaScript code.

Comment: It **_IS_** a duplicate since the generic/common/underlying problem is the same. Learning to see this is a major thing in finding solutions to problems quicker

Comment: "Learning to see this is a major thing in finding solutions to problems quicker" - Agreed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I found the solution and thought it will help.
Some valuable findings:

1. If you want to access bean variables in JavaScript, put the script inside form.

2. function inside **"onevent"** has its own variable called **"data"** and has different statuses(**begin, complete and success**). Do your task only when the status is **"success"** otherwise it will run 3 times.

 3. [JSF and Jquery AJAX - How can I make them work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082858/jsf-and-jquery-ajax-how-can-i-make-them-work-together/10083561#10083561) - Refer to this for more info on statuses

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="sampleList" value="#{beanName.tempValue}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select value..." itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="a" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="b" />
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{beanName.actionMethodToNavigate}" onevent="function(data){clickToNavigate(data, '#{beanName.tempValue}')}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<script>
    function clickToNavigate(data, value){
        if(data.status=="success"){
            if (value=='0'){ 
                return false;
            } else if (value=='a'){
                 jumpToAhchor('#listItems');
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A reference to a stackoverflow Q/A with the other 'statuses' would be great... Thanks!

Comment: just added. thanks!